# Laravel 4 app start event for change language

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to change the language in the laravel based on the Session value. I have tried few ways and I thought that I can do it with the laravel events.

I checked the documentation but there is no default event like app start. Is there anyother way which I can do it.

I need to do it without the URL prefixes. and there is no user auth system in the application. this is just a front-end application without any logins or DB access.

Thanks

Comment: There is application event in Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events

Comment: Thanks I used it and solved my problem